# How to get html content of component in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, printing, vue.js

I have a html template as below

**AdvanceTemplatePage.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="content edit-page management">
        <md-card class="page-card">
            <md-card-header class="page-card-header">
                <md-card-header-text class="page-title">
                    <div class="md-title">{{ 'AdvanceDetail' | translate }}</div>
                </md-card-header-text>
            </md-card-header>

            <md-card-content class="page-content">
                <div class="info-container">
                    <div class="label">{{ 'AdvanceStatus' | translate }}</div>
                    <div class="value">{{ '@AdvanceStatus' }}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="info-container">
                    <div class="label">{{ 'Amount' | translate }}</div>
                    <div class="value">{{ '@Amount' }} {{ '@Currency' }}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="info-container">
                    <div class="label">{{ 'RefundStartingAt' | translate }}</div>
                    <div class="value">{{ '@RefundStartingAt' }}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="info-container">
                    <div class="label">{{ 'RefundInstallmentQuantity' | translate }}</div>
                    <div class="value">{{ '@RefundInstallmentQuantity' }}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="info-container">
                    <div class="label">{{ 'Description' | translate }}</div>
                    <div class="value">{{ '@Description' }}</div>
                </div>
            </md-card-content>

        </md-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

I need to access this template html from another page.

I am trying to access html like this on another page, but I do not know how to do it.

```
import AdvanceTemplatePage from 'pages/print/template/AdvanceTemplatePage.vue';

methods: {
    onPrint() {
        const vm = this;
        const template = new AdvanceTemplatePage({ el: '#templateDiv' })
    }
}
```

How can i get html info from another page in vue.js

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to access the raw html, or the rendered html ?

Comment: actually I need both of them.I will use one on some pages, the other on some pages @Cobaltway

Comment: This is pretty old but for future ppl. Check vue web components https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The template will be compiled to a render function so your code won't work. And basically you can't get the original html template.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you want to get the source template content, the easiest way to achieve this is to save the template in a variable so that you can ref to it in the future.

Note that `.vue` doesn't support named exports so you need to put this in another `.js` file:

```
export const templateOfAdvanceTemplatePage = `
  <div class="content edit-page management">
    <md-card class="page-card">
     ...
    </md-card>
  </div>
`
```

and in your `AdvanceTemplatePage.vue`

```
import templateOfAdvanceTemplatePage from 'path/to/templateOfAdvanceTemplatePage.js'

export default {
  template: templateOfAdvanceTemplatePage,
  ...
}
```

Now you can simply import `templateOfAdvanceTemplatePage` everywhere you want since it's just a variable.

If you want the compiled html instead of the source template, I found out a tricky way to achieve. Simply render the component and use `innerHTML` to get the html:

in another component, you render but hide it, also give it a `ref`:

```
<template>
  ...
    <advance-template-page v-show="false" ref="foo"></advance-template-page>
  ...
</template>
```

now you can get the html content in your methods:

```
onPrint() {
    const template = this.$refs.foo.$el.innerHTML
}
```

Comment: any way to handle v-model ?
if A is base component and B is external component  and B uses v-model from A 
it fails

Answer (score 10):

You can just add `<slot></slot>` ([documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)) to your component

Comment: Just what I was looking for thanks! https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html